# Loading two script blocks (using lab.js as a load manager)

Tags: javascript, jquery, labjs, dynamic-script-loading

I'm trying to load two blocks of `lab.js` in different places but if I use functions in the second block from files loaded in the first block, they show as undefined.

This is the **first block** (loaded in the header template from my MVC project

```
<script>
$LAB
.script("<?php echo(GlobalConfig::$ROOT_URL); ?>scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js").wait()
.script("<?php echo(GlobalConfig::$ROOT_URL); ?>bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js").wait()
.script("<?php echo(GlobalConfig::$ROOT_URL); ?>bootstrap/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js").wait()
.script("<?php echo(GlobalConfig::$ROOT_URL); ?>scripts/libs/underscore-min.js").wait()
.script("<?php echo(GlobalConfig::$ROOT_URL); ?>scripts/libs/underscore.date.min.js").wait()
.script("<?php echo(GlobalConfig::$ROOT_URL); ?>scripts/libs/backbone-min.js").wait(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("loaded");
    });
});
</script>
```

this is the **second block** loaded at a content template

```
$LAB
.script("../scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js").wait(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".test-badges").each(function( index ) {
            $( this ).tooltip({
              'show':true,
              'placement': 'bottom',
              'title' : 'Marca esta casilla si consideras que tu compañer@ debe responder igual.'
            });

        });
    });
});
```

The functions from second block (.tooltip) are not loaded because they are a dependancy from jquery. **There is no way to unify both blocks** in just a block loaded in header (both files are completly independent and have content created dynamically, also it's not what I'm trying to achieve)

So the question is .. Is there a way to tell the second block to only load when the first block is completly loaded?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are creating two separate $LAB chains and that what you want can be achieved by storing a reference to your $LAB chain and chaining your last call to the end, like so:

First block:

```
<script>
var chain = $LAB
.script("<?php echo(GlobalConfig::$ROOT_URL); ?>scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js").wait()
.script("<?php echo(GlobalConfig::$ROOT_URL); ?>bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js").wait()
.script("<?php echo(GlobalConfig::$ROOT_URL); ?>bootstrap/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js").wait()
.script("<?php echo(GlobalConfig::$ROOT_URL); ?>scripts/libs/underscore-min.js").wait()
.script("<?php echo(GlobalConfig::$ROOT_URL); ?>scripts/libs/underscore.date.min.js").wait()
.script("<?php echo(GlobalConfig::$ROOT_URL); ?>scripts/libs/backbone-min.js")
</script>
```

Second block:

```
chain.wait(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".test-badges").each(function( index ) {
            $( this ).tooltip({
              'show':true,
              'placement': 'bottom',
              'title' : 'Marca esta casilla si consideras que tu compañer@ debe responder igual.'
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried it and It's still giving a syntax error. Surely the error comes from that double declaration of $lab but it's still not working like that. I'm using a workaround right now defining jquery out of the load chain but it still not a good idea

Comment: That's strange... do you have a jsfiddle example to play with? Also, I hate to suggest this but I have to check: isn't .tooltip in jquery UI? Are you sure it's being loaded at all?